# Python: Can't do .date() function on a datetime object in certain contexts

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, openpyxl, python-datetime

I'm parsing through an Excel spreadsheet and having problems with date formatting. Column `A` and `S` are strings, column `R` is a date. This is my code. The issue comes when I try to get the `.date()` from my datetime object in column `R` in the variable `install_date`.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter
from datetime import date, datetime
from pprint import pprint
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'schedule.xlsx')
warnings.simplefilter("default")
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Master Schedule')

schedule = {}

for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    site = str(sheet['A' + str(row)].value)
    idate = sheet['R' + str(row)].value
    status = str(sheet['S' + str(row)].value)
    install_date = idate.date()
    sid = "{0}-{1}".format(site,install_date)

    if 'Pending' in status:
        schedule[sid] = {'site': site, 'install_date': install_date, 'status': status}
    else:
        pass
```

If I run this script I get this in the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sheet.py", line 18, in <module>
    install_date = idate.date()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'date'
```

If I do `type(idate)` I get `<type 'datetime.datetime'>` and its value is `datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 17, 0, 0)`

And if I do this `print idate.date()`, I get the output that I expect and want: `2016-08-10`.

What am I missing here? I feel like the type is changing at random on me. If I simplify my script and select a single specific cell to work with (`R251` for example) I can perform the `.date()` function on it without issue. I just can't seem to find how doing it in the for loop is making such a difference.

Edit: Solved by EngineerCamp. I needed to retool the script to have the `if 'Pending' in status:` check happen at the beginning of the iteration since there are rows without dates in that column. New code:

```
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    status = str(sheet['S' + str(row)].value)
    if 'Pending' in status:
        site = str(sheet['A' + str(row)].value)
        idate = sheet['R' + str(row)].value
        install_date = idate.date()
        sid = "{0}-{1}".format(site,install_date)
        schedule[sid] = {'site': site, 'install_date': install_date, 'status': status}
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Is it possible that there is no datetime object in one of the rows and therefore an error only occurs when you loop over that row?

Comment: @EngineerCamp - That's it! I knew it immediately when I read your comment. I think I'd just been staring at it too long. I've improved the code quite a bit now that I'm account for that. Thank you very much!